# the dollar bill my grandma gave me: relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses

Consider these noun-phrases:

> the dollar bill my grandma gave me
>
> the woolen mittens my grandma gave me

Is **my grandma gave me** an integrated relative clause and if so, what are its antecedents in these phrases?

Comment: It must be restrictive because it has no relative word such as *that* or *which*. Only restrictive relatives can appear without a relative word. The second test is that you can insert the word *that* in your example. The word *that* cannot freely appear in non-restrictive or "supplementary" relative clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly correct.   "[that] my grandma gave to me" is a restrictive integrated relative clause.  Its antecedent is "The dollar bill".

By definition, the antecedent of an integrated relative clause is always the remainder/head of the noun phrase it is contained in.

The relative pronoun "that" can usually be omitted, as in your examples, if the the antecedent is not the subject of the relative clause.

Comment: It is quite acceptable to omit "that" in formal writing

Answer (score 0):

> the dollar bill my grandma gave me

> the woolen mittens my grandma gave me

"my grandma gave me" is a reduced relative clause; the omitted relativiser **that** has antecedent *the dollar bill*.

Example 2 has the same construction.

Comment: Do you understand the clause to be integrated/restrictive?

Comment: yes, the clause is an integrated relative clause (which is also called restrictive relative clause).  Only this type can have its relative pronoun/relativiser omitted.

Comment: I don't think there's any meaning to the idea of "integrated / restrictive" unless you have a full context. Such as *The dollar bill, [which] my grandma gave me, was all the money I had*, AND *The dollar bill [which] my grandma gave me didn't look like the one grandpa gave me on my last birthday*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You can't leave out *which* in your non-restrictive example. And you can't use the relative word *that*, either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You can "think" whatever you choos - in this case that these terms don't have "any meaning" - or you can refer to CGEL 2002  p. 1034 for the definitions of "integrated" and "restrictive" relative clause.  Without the "that" it is called a "bare relative".  Usage is given that is absolutely parallel to that in this question.  Additionally, Aracuaria's comments about why your examples are incorrect are absolutely apt.   Heal thyself, physician.